# How do you collect specific information from DownloadString?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to gather information from a website API link, the API displays the information in plaintext, so for example creation date is:

> "created_at":"2013-11-13T16:02:49.071386Z"

Now in my program I want to display only certain parts of that information in a TextBox. So I'm going to have a Label saying what the information is, in this case it will be "Creation Date:" and then next to it I want the TextBox to display only "2013-11-13" in this example.

Currently I can display all the information at once using a function, which is messy and all in one TextBox and it looks like this:

```
 Public Function Information()
    Dim blank As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim browser As New WebClient
    Dim info As String = browser.DownloadString("API")
    If info.Contains("display_name") Then
        TextBox2.AppendText(blank + " = " + info + vbCrLf)
    Else

    End If
End Function
```

I'm new to all this, so sorry if it sounds stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked again, I'm guessing that the data you're downloading is actually JSON. In that case, you probably ought to be treating it as JSON rather than just plain text. That probably means using JSON.NET, which you can add as a NuGet package. You would feed the JSON text in and get access to objects containing the parsed data. I've left my original answer below for completeness though.

ORIGINAL:

`DownloadString` downloads a `String`. That's it, that's all. What you do with that `String` is completely up to you. It's just like any other `String`. That means that the `DownloadString` method is irrelevant to the question.

If the actual text you get is indeed this:

> "created_at":"2013-11-13T16:02:49.071386Z"

i.e. the double-quotes are part of the text, then you can do this to get the two substrings of interest:

```vb
Dim parts = info.Split({":"c}, 2)

For i = 0 To parts.GetUpperBound(0)
    parts(i) = parts(i).Trim(ControlChars.Quote)
Next
```

How you then want to go about converting the "created_at" to "Creation Date" is up to you. As for the date part, there are two ways you could go about it. You could just call `String.Split` again, e.g.

```vb
Dim [date] = parts(1).Split("T"c)(0)
```

Alternatively, you could use `Date.ParseExact` to convert the text to an actual `Date` and then format that however you want, e.g.

```vb
Dim dt = Date.ParseExact(parts(1), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ", Nothing)
Dim [date] = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

The first option is easier if you just want the date in the same format but the second option will allow you to use a different format if you want and you've also got the time if you need for something else.